# adding tinynav to wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme and I want to use the tinynav jQuery plugin.

I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/mbn-jq/tinynav.js"></script>
```

into the header and when I use firebug I can see it fine, under the call to the jQuery

Next, into the bottom of the tinynav.js file I added the function:

```
$(function () {
$("#menu-main").tinyNav();
});
```

right at the very bottom.

Then I added into the style sheet:

```
.tinynav { display: block }
#menu-main { display: none }
```

NOw as I go through the break point my menu disappears but the dropdown doesn't appear

When I look at the code I can see that it hasn't added any  tags so somethings not working at all!

Comment: the question really is I guess where should the little bit of code where $(#menu-main).tinyNav(); go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try this wordpress plugin ..

[**https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinynav/**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinynav/)

Comment: well, I wanted to see if I could do it from scratch really - like to try to understand these things. But I could give up and use the plugin - so thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little old but still relevant... - I use [tinynav](http://tinynav.viljamis.com/) a lot as it is very light-weight;

1) First check that you have included the required libraries.  You should probably use wp-enque-script / css - but I am echoing here, that included from the orginal site (http://tinynav.viljamis.com/).  Note you may not need to include the jquery min file as the WP included version be fine;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/tinynav.js"></script>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

2) Check to make sure you have used jQuery no conflict in the tinynav.js script.  Also use Firebug to check the #menu-main-nav is the correct class or ID;

```
 $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function(){
            $j('#menu-main-nav').tinyNav({
   active: 'current-menu-item' // Set the "active" class
   // header: 'Menu', // String: Specify text for "header" and show header instead of the active item       
});
});
```

3) In your mobile.css - ensure the following at the top of the file:

```
.tinynav { 
display:none 
}
```

4) then at the break points ensure you are displaying tinynav fine;

```
/*-------------------------------------------*/
/* #MOBILE 320px (Portrait)*/
/*-------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) , screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {


/* Hide Main Nav UL - replace with tinynav */

#mainMenu ul {
display: none !important;
}

.tinynav {
display: block !important;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
border: 1px solid #666;
color: #111;
}


} /* end break point */
```